# How can I debug layout file processing in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento-2.0, debugging

According to magento 2 theme specification about Layout files processing :

> The Magento application processes layout files in the following order:
>
> 1/ Collects all layout files from modules. The order is determined by the
>   modules order in the module list from app/etc/config.php.
>
> 2./ Determines
>   the sequence of inherited themes [, ...,
>   ]
>
> 3./ Iterates the sequence of themes from
>   last ancestor to current:
>
> a.    Adds all extending theme layout files to the list.
>
> b.    Replaces overridden layout files in the list.
>
> 4./ Merges all layout files from the list.

How can I debug and view the layout file for every step of this process ?

Comment: Do you mean where to put break points? Or what would you expect?

Comment: Hi, Thank you. My main purpose is printing  "merges all layout file" to see how magento 2 layout render. I have added my answer as the below.

Comment: @ thienphucvx, I used your code but I am unable to create .xml at var/log . Do I need to change anything ?

Comment: Could you try to debug to make sure that you created that module correctly like "var_dump something on excute method of observer" to check whether it's working or not ?

Comment: Have a look to this developer app, it  may help you in the debug process: https://github.com/magespecialist/mage-chrome-toolbar

Comment: It looks promising for developer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally, I can print all loaded xml layout and know how magento 2 layout is working. It also help us to check whether our custom module layout is loaded or not.
The idea is :

- We listen to an event “**layout_generate_blocks_after**” and get all loaded tree from that point.
- Save all loaded tree to an xml file.

1/ We create a new directory `Sample/Dev`.
Create `Sample/Dev/registration.php` to declare with Magento 2 about our module directory.

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sample_Dev',
    __DIR__
);
```

2/ Create `Sample/Dev/etc/module.xml` : To let Magento 2 know about setup version of our module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="module.xsd">
    <module name="Sample_Dev" setup_version="1.0.0" schema_version="1.0.0" release_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

3/ Create `Sample/Dev/etc/frontend/events.xml`. In this file, we will listen to event **“layout_generate_blocks_after”**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="thienphucvx_layout_generate_blocks_after" instance="Sample\Dev\Model\Layout" />
    </event>

</config>
```

4/ Create `Sample/Dev/Model/Layout.php` with the content as below

```
<?php

namespace Sample\Dev\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class Layout  implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct ( \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $xml = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getXmlString();
        /*$this->_logger->debug($xml);*//*If you use it, check ouput string xml in var/debug.log*/
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/layout_block.xml');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info($xml);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

5/ Set up new module . 
In your home website directory. enter CMD command line:

– php bin/magento module:enable Sample_Dev

– php bin/magento setup:upgrade

6/ Refresh the page that you want to see xml file (for example: your home page)  and check your handle xml file  in `var/log/layout_block.xml` .

Comment: I just came across this and it is amazing. Would you mind submitting a PR to Magento 2 so everyone can have this feature? Even releasing a module would help tremendously.

Comment: Hi Mbalparda,
 I don't know how to do it. Could you help me to submit it ?

Comment: Yep pinged you on Twitter.

Comment: where is the issue/pull-request for upvoting ? link ?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10533