# Template not being loaded

Tags: layout, magento2.1.5, page-layouts

**UPDATE:** I implemented [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97343/how-can-i-debug-layout-file-processing-in-magento-2) solution to check the loading of layout which confirms that my layout is being loaded. But not my template.

**UPDATE 2:** I even tried installing another version of magento 2.1.11 but the issue persists whereas everything works fine in my old project (magento2.1.5) from where I've taken out the module.
**UPDATE 3:** Weirdest thing is no any template of my previously working modules is loaded in these fresh installations.

I have developed a module which works perfectly and I copied that module in a fresh magento installation. My `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="paym" frontName="paym">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

My controller is `Vendor\Module\Controller\Redirect\Index.php`

```
<?php  
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Redirect;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

My `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/paym_redirect_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\PaymentProcessor" name="custompayment" template="Vendor_Module::redirect.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

My template is `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/redirect.phtml`

```
<?php 
echo 'hello';
die();
?>
```

The issue is template does not load. When I write `echo 'hi'; die();` in controller it shows up.

Another weird thing I have noticed is when I randomly delete a matching tag in `paym_redirect_index.xml` and run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` no error occurs. But in real any small error in `.xml` file would never allow any magento command to execute. I even removed

```
     </body>
</page>
```

and `<?xml version="1.0"?>` one by one, no error occurs in command line.
Also no error in logs, console. 
I have enabled php error reporting by writing on the top of index.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

I have renamed `pub/errors/local.sample.xml` to `local.xml`.
But the thing is a blank screen loads without any error. Can anyone help me debug this issue?

Comment: Issue seems to be with your layout file name , Your layout file name should be `router_controller_action.xml`

Comment: Hello @Piyush , actually this is fine, you may see that above.

Comment: your module is enable?

Comment: @KeyurShah, yes I checked in CLI, backend and `/app/etc/config.php` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The block class you are calling is `Vendor\Module\Block\PaymentProcessor`, does this exist? If it does, it needs to extend the template class `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` to be able to render the template. Just to test this out, call the template class in your XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custompayment" template="Vendor_Module::redirect.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This should render the template onto the page. From there you should be able to create or change the block class to fix the problem for your module.

Comment: The block class exists which inherits the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`

Comment: i just copied all your code, only changing the vendor namespace and the module name. I added in the code from my answer (using the Magento block class and not a custom one) and my template file is showing up correctly. So it's not your XML code, it's not your controller code and it's not the module not being enabled. I think it's your block class, bit that code is not posted. Also, it might just be the cache, i clear that before most page loads, so it might be worth doing here.

Comment: you are right that there is no error in my code. But It seems like some issued in magento 2.

Comment: Could it be related to CACHE_TAG used in model cache?