# Wrong Layouts in Magento2 Adminhtml

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml, page-layouts

I noticed a strange behavior in a M2 System, I think this is related to a 3rd party module. All layouts which should be 1column layouts are 2 column layouts actually so something overwrites the default behavior. In conclusion, they got the wrong body class *page-layout-admin-2columns-left* instead of *page-layout-admin-1column*. I followed this thread [How can I debug layout file processing in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97343/how-can-i-debug-layout-file-processing-in-magento-2) to debug this, but can't see anything wrong. So my questions are, how to debug this? Any hints are helpful.

[image]

Cheers,
Jan

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I cannot figure out how to fix this. Can you elaborate a little on how you fixed this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

- I did a "locate adminhtml/layout/default.xml"

  - Within those files I did a grep on string "layout"
  - I could identify a module which sets the wrong layout which overwrites the default behaviour

Anyway, many thanks @Imran